# What does 'iconic' mean in the context of the reduplication in Latin 'carcer'?

Tags: etymology

> [incarceration (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=incarceration&allowed_in_frame=0)
>       "fact of being imprisoned," 1530s, from Medieval Latin *incarcerationem* (nominative *incarceratio*), noun of action from past participle stem of *incarcerare* "to imprison," from *in-* "in" (see [in-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-&allowed_in_frame=0) (2)) + carcer "prison, an enclosed space,"
>   from Proto-Italic **kar-kr(o)-*, of uncertain origin.
>
> > It seems best to connect *carcer* with other IE words for 'circle, round object', such as [Latin] *curvus*, [Greek] *κιρκος* 'ring', [Old Norse] *hringr*, although not all of these have a good IE etymology. The reduplication in Latin *carcer* could be **iconic**; thus, the original meaning would have been 'enclosure'. [de Vaan]
>
> [...]

What does 'iconic' mean or refer to here? I researched [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90882?redirectedFrom=iconic#eid) but remain confused.

Comment: http://pandora.cii.wwu.edu/vajda/ling201/test1materials/Signs_handout.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a long time since I did any linguistics, but *iconic* features are said to be features in which (my paraphrase) form supports function. In other words, if somebody was late to come and meet me and I said, "It sure took you a long time to get here!" and extended the vowel in "long" so that it took a long time, that would be iconic.

Another example of iconic use would be the fact that in the series "high, higher, highest," the further in the series you go, the higher the number of [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme).

The poetic device [onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) is a specific form of iconic language.

So what the passage you quoted is saying is that *carcer* could have started out as *cur* or *cir* or *cer* or the like, meaning something circular, and then the syllable was doubled to represent something VERY circular—a prison that enclosed a person entirely, a circle that didn't let anybody out.

I myself find this a little fuzzy, but it's certainly possible.

I can't think of any iconic reduplication in English, but if you read the work of Sharon Inkelas, linguistics professor at UC Berkeley ([this](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/~inkelas/Papers/2013HandbookOfDerivationInkelas.pdf) for example) you may find something (and you'll certainly find her referring to it in other languages).